# Flash AS3 - Characters sometimes go missing from TextFields

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm using AS3 on CS6 and setting text in a TextField. I have a few different fields that are having this issue.

Sometimes when I test the app, the text fields appear empty or sometimes it has characters missing. This doesn't happen all the time and appears to be completely random, I don't even have to change anything for it to come back.

The fonts are embedded, which shouldn't be the issue anyway because it randomly disappears and reappears when I rerun the test now and again.

It doesn't happen with all text fields either. Here is the code to the +ADD button

```
var textFormat:TextFormat = (buyButton_mc.getChildByName("buyText") as TextField).getTextFormat();

var buyButtonText = (buyButton_mc.getChildByName("buyText") as TextField);
var btnBg = (buyButton_mc.getChildByName("btn_bg") as MovieClip);
buyButtonText.embedFonts = true;

textFormat.size = (minRowHeight - 2) - 8;
textFormat.color = BubbleStoreMain.instance.licenseBoxColors['selected']['text'];

buyButtonText.text = "+ADD";
buyButtonText.y -= 3;
buyButtonText.setTextFormat(textFormat);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you `trace(buyButtonText.text)`?

Comment: @Pier Thanks for the idea, when I trace it, it comes with with the full text that's supposed to be there, even when it's not visible. What does this mean?

Comment: It means the problem is somewhere else... try tracing different properties from the textfield and see if something changes when the text doesn't show up. For example `trace(buyButtonText.textHeight);`

Comment: I've traced everything and it's all normal. I think it's bug with with my Flash install as my developer was working on the same files and he didn't experience it at all. He's using CS5.5 and i'm using CS6. I've reinstalled it but no luck. I can't imagine it being code because it's just so random.

Comment: @Pier ah looks like it is the code. I've narrowed it down to the fact that they are the only bold text fields in the app where the fonts are embedded. If I remove the bold it shows. Why do you think this may be?

Comment: I have no idea... Flash is known for having all sorts of bugs with fonts. Did you try with another font?